# Cauchy's theorem in a disk (Proof Verification)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Consider the following proof of Cauchy's theorem in a disk.  My question is pasted at the bottom of the picture.  (Note that in the proof below, a reference is made to "Theorem 2".  In my textbook "Theorem 2" is just Cauchy's theorem in a rectangle.)

[image]

**Question:** While I agree that the proof establishes that

$$
\int_\sigma f\ dz = 0
$$

why does this result generalize to all closed curves $\gamma$ inside $\Delta$ that might looking nothing like $\sigma$?  That is why do we have that

$$
\int_\sigma f(z)\ dz = 0 \implies \int_\gamma f(z)\ dz = 0 \text{?}
$$

I take it the last paragraph of the proof answers this question, but for some reason I don't understand what it's saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first paragraph is not meant to show $\int_\sigma f \,dz=0$; its purpose is to show that there exists an analytic function $F$ in $\Delta$ such that $F'=f$. Once this is obtained, the statement about $\int_\gamma f\,dz$ follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals: the integral of $f$ is equal to the difference of the values of $F$ at the endpoints. For a closed curve, the endpoints coincide and so the difference is zero.